# .NET 5 produces Error while copying content to a stream when throwing custom exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stream

Below are symptoms of the problem, the *GetAsync* method is bugged.

---

Consider the custom exception:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class FooException : Exception
{
    public FooException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public FooException(string type, int key) : base(FormatMessage(type, key)) { }
    public FooException(string type, string key) : base(FormatMessage(type, key)) { }
    protected FooException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }

    private static string FormatMessage<T>(string type, T key)
    {
        return $"{type} not found for key '{key}'.";
    }
}
```

When this is thrown, caught and parsed in a controller we receive the following message:

*System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Error while copying content to a stream.*

We can solve this issue by following the typical exception pattern here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-localized-exception-messages and by moving the formatting to a separate class like below:

```cs
public static class ExceptionMessageFormatter
{
    public static string FormatMessage<T>(string type, T key)
    {
        return $"{type} not found for key '{key}'.";
    }
}
```

And then the following exception pattern:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class FooException : Exception
{
    public FooException() { }
    public FooException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public FooException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
    protected FooException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
}
```

This is solution that works for me but I still don't know why the initial exception didn't work as we expect, why is this? Is there a bug in .NET 5?

Comment: A) your first example doesn't have the `[Serializable]`, is that a C+P error, or is it missing from your actual code?  B) Your second example doesn't call the message formatter, is that a C+P error?

Comment: Yes @Neil, it is a C&P error, and the reason why is because I've taken the formatter out of the class so the caller would use that instead and parse the string instead

Comment: Are you saying that original exception code DOES have [Serializable] on the class?  The error message suggests that it doesn't.

Comment: Yes it does, I've edited the original question now thanks

Comment: Pretty unclear where *type* and *key* could come from in the proposed workaround.  Surely the real problem is located in whatever code you use to display or log the exception.  You don't know anything unless it also displays the exception's InnerException.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it's due to the *GetAsync* method not working properly: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23870#issuecomment-435189110

```cs
// Workaround: Split the call into HeadersRead, check status code and if it is ok, continue with body read
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
Console.WriteLine($"{response.StatusCode} - {(int)response.StatusCode}"); // Prints "Unauthorized - 401"
// Throws the 'bad' unexpected exception
string body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: I don't think changing how your Exception is constructed is related to that issue?